# The name of effect of liquid flow inducing flow to neighboring layers of liquid?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, terminology

How do you call an effect, when liquid or gas stream is involving the neighboring layers of matter also move?

Like on videos of rocket engines testing, when exhausting gas sucks an air and steam from behind an engine?

RS-25 testing video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hG8odscqlfI

An effect is visible in an inset, where the nozzle is shown from above.

**UPDATE**

[Bladeless fans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bladeless_fan) work on the base of this effect:

[image]

Air is emitted by the circle only, but it involves entire mass in the center to move.

**UPDATE 2**

Also [injector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injector) seemedly uses this

[image]

Unfortunately it is said it uses [Venturi effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venturi_effect), but I need term about movement, not pressure...

Comment: Are you referring to [shear viscosity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity#Dynamic_.28shear.29_viscosity)?

Comment: Yes shear viscosity is the basis of this effect, but it has special name in whole.

Comment: How about drag?

Comment: Is this common term?

Comment: Is the term entrainment?

Comment: I was going to say entrainment by frictional drag/viscosity.

Answer (score 2):

[Entrainment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entrainment_%28hydrodynamics%29) of a fluid by viscous drag.